# Parsing HTML in android with JSOUP

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse some html from a website. I connect to a website in an AsyncTask. I try to parse the retrieved HTML with JSOUP parser.

```
website= task.get();
            String items="";
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(website);
            Element content = doc.getElementById("rtable");
            Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("tr");
            for (Element link : links) {
             items=items+ link.child(2).text()+link.child(3).text()+ link.child(0).getElementsByTag("a").attr("href");

            }
            mDateDisplay.setText(items);
```

If I parse the html in a normal java project it works fine but not in the Android project. I get a null pointer exception in the line:

```
Element content = doc.getElementById("rtable");
```

THe output of the error:

```
11-25 16:42:30.674: W/System.err(972): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 16:42:30.684: W/System.err(972):  at com.example.seminarska.Prevozi.onCreate(Prevozi.java:89)
11-25 16:42:30.684: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-25 16:42:30.684: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-25 16:42:30.684: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-25 16:42:30.694: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-25 16:42:30.694: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-25 16:42:30.694: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-25 16:42:30.731: W/System.err(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 16:42:30.734: W/System.err(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 16:42:30.734: W/System.err(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-25 16:42:30.761: W/System.err(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 16:42:30.764: W/System.err(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-25 16:42:30.764: W/System.err(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-25 16:42:30.764: W/System.err(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-25 16:42:30.774: W/System.err(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Oh, the website I am trying to parse is [this](https://prevoz.org/?f=&fc=SI&t=&tc=SI&d=0000-00-00#results).

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements img = doc.select("img");
for (Element el : img)
{
    String imageUrl = el.attr("src");
    images.add(imageUrl);
}
```

Comment: Error on line at 89: `com.example.seminarska.Prevozi.onCreate(Prevozi.java:89)`